# Suitable resistance values for an analog IC

Tags: analog, integrated-circuit, circuit-design, filter

I was reading a chapter of the book "Continuous-Time Active Filter Design" about analog filters design. Let's consider the following band - pass filter, in which its inductances may be simulated with some GIC (Generalized Impedance Converter) circuits:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMVb5.png]

The book says that this circuit is impractical because of the presence of 0.6 Ohm resistors, which are too low. Now my question is: which are suitable values for an IC?

I have always read that the main problem is to get high resistors (since it would mean long conductive paths to get them, and so large occupied silicon area). But which is the problem of getting 0.6Ohm resistors? If it is a problem, why should not be a problem realizing the short circuit interconnections of components?

---

Here the internal structure of the GIC:

[image]

Comment: To answer this we would need to understand the gyrator circuit inside the boxes marked s.

Comment: Yes, I'll put a schematic now

Comment: You must realize that circuits can be **scaled**. A filter works on the **ratio** of impedances. So if you increase all impedances by a factor 10 (resistors x 10, capacitors / 10) then the filter would behave identically. The issue with this filter is that there's a factor 1000 between 600 ohm / 0.6 ohm. **But** the 0.6 ohm sits "behind" the GIC. There's still room for flexibilty there. A GIC also works on ratios of impedances so it can be scaled as well. That allows you to scale only the circuit between the GICs (with 0.6 ohm and 12 ohm) but not the 600 ohm resistors.

Comment: On chip a 0.6 ohm resistor can be made but it is impractical and might take up too much area. However, in this case it's not needed. When designing the real filter from the **prototype** above, a designer would apply scaling to the design so that we don't even need the 0.6 ohm resistors. On a chip we usually strive to have resistors between 1k ohm and 100 kohm (1 M ohm if there's a high-resistance poly layer available).

Comment: also, these pictures stylistically look like they are from a 1970s' book – so the opamps that were available at the time simply might not have had a very low output impedance and/or high bias currents. It'd be relevant to know what the authors assume about their opamps.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie why does it occupy too much area? I thought the area increases with the resistance value

Comment: @Kinka-Byo nope, for a high-ohmic resistor, you can just use slightly doped silicon and lay out a thin trace. For a low-ohmic resistor, you'd need to do it either in a looong trace of metal layer, or in a very wiiiide trace of highly doped silicon. Then, you get into all sorts of accuracy problems.

Comment: *the area increases with the resistance value* That's true but assumes that you're making a resistor that has a larger value than the square resistance. Say you have 1 kohm/sq then for 10 kohm you need 10 squares **in series**, a W/L = 1/10 resistor. But if you need 100 ohms you need 10 squares **in parallel** so W/L = 10/1. You generally cannot make very wide, very short (small L) resistors as that's not allowed. Also, to make an **accurate** filter you want to use resistors that all use the same material. Making some resistors poly and others metal will give inaccuracies.

Comment: I think the problem with the 0.6\$\Omega\$ resistors is not so much that they are hard to make but that they consume enormous amounts of power in any practical filter.